# Releasing AWS SQS Message back to queue from Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, queue, amazon-sqs

I'm using Lumen (Laravel) to handle an AWS SQS queue with the [sqs-plain driver](https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-plain-sqs) for the connection. That driver works the same way as the default sqs driver but allows me to use custom JSON in the queue message body.

Based on that package I've created a job handler that works fine, but I'm having trouble understanding how to properly release a message back to the queue.

In the handler method I've injected a [SqsJob](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/SqsJob.html) and tried calling the `release` method which isn't working as I'd expect.

It seems that the method `SqsJob::release` calls `changeMessageVisibility` on the SQS API and the parent release method, which simply sets a class variable `$this->released = true;` on the job.

So the "releasing" of the message isn't really done, as much as the message is just being marked as released and the visibility of the message in the queue is changed. Not handling the release would result in the message being "handled" and deleted from the queue.

By trial and error I found out, that throwing an exception in the handler method sends the message back to the queue.

Here's a simplified version of the job handler:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job as LaravelJob;
use Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\SqsJob;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class HandlerJob extends Job
{
    protected $data;

    /**
     * @param SqsJob $job
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function handle(SqsJob $job, array $data)
    {
        if ($this->validData($data)) {
            // handle the job
        } else {
            $this->release(60);

            // actually release the job back to queue
            throw new \Exception('Invalid Data');
        }
    }

    private function validData($data)
    {
        //not relevant
    }
}
```

This seems like a basic task to be handled by the queue worker but I can't figure it out.

**What is the proper way of releasing a message back into the the queue using the Laravel/Lumen framework?**